# Possible empty argument when calling method

Tags: java, oop

Hello I have to make a frog catch a fly. I have been given the code they will use to test the method and they will use both

```
catchFly();

catchFly(3);
```

is there a way to cater for both possibilities if this were to happen, as I do not know how to check if there are nor arguments

```
   public void catchFly()

   {

         super.catchFly();
         account.credit(100);
         super.yellow();
         super.jump();
         super.green();

   }
```

Comment: You mean, other than creating a method `public void catchFly(int n) {...}`? If you're worried about code modifications, you can change the code of `catchFly` to simply call the other method: `public void catchFly() { catchFly(100); }`.

Comment: I thought that if you done it that way and the user never gave an argument it wouldnt work? or am i wrong?

Comment: If you have 2 methods, one with parametres and one without, and you make your method call without, that that,s the one that will be called.

Comment: @AntonH thanks that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define the method which requires the argument:

```
public void catchFly(int value) {
    super.catchFly();
    account.credit(value);
    super.yellow();
    super.jump();
    super.green();
}
```

Which you can use when the value is known:

```
catchFly(3);
```

Then for cases where the value isn't known, define an overload which supplies the hard-coded default value:

```
public void catchFly() {
    catchFly(100);
}
```

Which you can call without an argument:

```
catchFly();
```

In cases like this the overloads are generally pass-through methods which invoke the main logic method, simply providing defaults where needed.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible, **method overloading** is the name for that

just define another method with the same name but other argument (see what is a signature of a method)

```
public void catchFly(int whatEver){
     super.catchFly();
     account.credit(whatEver);
     super.yellow();
     super.jump();
     super.green();
}
```